# Completeness of the space $C[0,1]$ relative to different norms

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I met with a multiple choice question:

Q. The space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is complete with respect to the norm,

1. $||f||_\infty=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}$
2. $||f||_1=\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|dx$
3. $||f||_{\infty}^{0,1}=||f||_\infty+|f(1)|+|f(0)|$
4. $||f||_2=\sqrt{\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^2} dx$

My attempt:

Option $(1)$ and $(3)$ is evident from the fact that 'point-wise limit of any Cauchy sequence will be also a uniform limit and continuous ',

For Option $(2)$, I have taken the sequence

$$f_n(x) := \begin{cases}
 0   & \text{if $0 \le x \le \frac1{2}$}\\
 n(x-\frac{1}{2}) & \text{if $\frac {1}{2} < x \le \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n}$}\\
 1              & \text{if $ \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{n} <x \leq 1 $}
\end{cases}$$

to show $||f_n-f_m||_1 \leq \frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{n}$ for $m \leq n$ while the limiting function is not continuous at $\frac{1}{2}$,

Can we consider the above sequence to deal with Option (4)? while I am stuck at $$||f_n-f_m||_2 \leq (1-\frac{m}{n})^2\frac{1}{m},$$
How to proceed? Can we extend the approach for any $p-$ norm $||\cdot ||_p$ on $C[0,1]$?

Comment: It is true that $f_n$ doesn't converge in $\lVert \bullet\rVert_1$ to a continuous function. However, exhibiting a discontinuous function $g$ such that $f_n\to g$ pointwise is not necessarily relevant in that regard. It is if you know general facts about convergence in $L^1$ on finite measure spaces, but you may not. Another thing you can do is proving that if $f_n\to g$ in that norm and $g$ is continuous, then $g(x)=1$ for $x>1/2$ and $g(x)=0$ for$x<1/2$.

Comment: The same example with the same idea should work for all $p$-norms. You should not even need interesting estimates to speak of.

Comment: I am also not entirely convinced by the explanation of 3. Sure, you are right, the space is complete. But that justification seems too flimsy. What you REALLY need to prove is that the identity operator $I\colon (C[0, 1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty) \to (C[0, 1], \lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty^{0, 1})$ is bijective, continuous, with continuous inverse. This is actually very easy to prove. An immediate consequence is that $(C[0, 1], \lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty^{0, 1})$ is complete, because $(C[0, 1], \lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty)$ is.

Comment: That's all you need for $(1)\equiv (3)$ :  $\ $   $\|f\|_\infty \le \|f\|_\infty^{0,1}\le 2\|f\|_\infty.$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Can you indicate the concept used to say the same example ($f_n$)  will work for $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: @MessiLio The concept is to calculate everything and prove that it converges to $0$ as $\min\{m,n\}\to\infty$, hence Cauchy. Then you do the proof I've already indicated for $L^1$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I am sure about $||f||_\infty \leq ||f||_\infty^{0,1} \leq 3||f||_\infty$, But how to say $||f||_{\infty}^{0,1} \leq 2 ||f||_\infty$?

Comment: @MessiLio My mistake.